# HTML5 image rotate with imagemap doesn't work in IE 8. Why?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-8, rotation

I have an image with an imagemap. The imagemap split the image in 4 sectors (top, right, bottom, left). Everytime u click a sector (imagemap area) the image rotate until this sector is on top.
I created a small example to show how I did it:
http://jsfiddle.net/44YhF/

Or as full HTML-Document:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jQueryRotate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- QueryRotate is from: https://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/files/jQueryRotate.js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
rotated=0;
aktuell=0;
isRotating=false;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$("#map area").click(function(event) {
console.log("click");
    event.preventDefault(); //bringt auch nichts
    if(!isRotating||true) {  //true hier raus nehmen damit die einzelnen Abschnitte nur klickbar sind wenn gerade keine Rotation läuft

        isRotating=true;
        pos=0;
        if(aktuell<$(this).attr("pos")) {
            pos=$(this).attr("pos");
        } else {
            pos=parseInt($(this).attr("pos"))+4;
        }
        rotatedif=360-(Math.abs(aktuell-pos)*90);
        rotate=rotated+rotatedif;

        aktuell=$(this).attr("pos");

        $("#cycle").rotate({animateTo:rotate, duration:(10-(Math.abs(aktuell-pos)))*300, callback: setRotatingOff});

        rotated=rotate;

    }
});


function setRotatingOff() {
    isRotating=false;
}

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://uploads6.wikipaintings.org/images/m-c-escher/circle-limit-iii.jpg!Blog.jpg" id="cycle" border="0" usemap="#map">
<map id="map" name="map">
<area shape="poly" coords="82,73,250,248,429,91," href="#" alt="" title=""   pos="0"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="421,85,250,246,417,419," href="#" alt="" title=""   pos="1"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="249,247,412,418,75,414," href="#" alt="" title=""   pos="2"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="248,247,74,411,82,76," href="#" alt="" title=""   pos="3"/>
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox, IE9/10. But in IE8, the Image rotate only the first time you click an area. After the first click, no more clickevents are fired when u click an area.

What can I do to get this working in IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case I can use a little trick:
I use a transparent image over the original image and use the map on the transparent image. So i can rotate the original image without rotating the imagemap.

Comment: Well done for finding a solution; I've given you +1 because it's a good pragmatic approach to fixing the problem without having to do the major rewrite I was suggesting. I still think my answer would be better if you were starting from scratch, but if your solution works for you, then it's the way to go. Well done. You should click the 'tick' icon to accept the answer so others can see that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support standard CSS `transform:rotate`; it uses a proprietary activeX `filter` method instead. jQuery hides this from you by giving you a standard method to call, but behind the scenes it works very differently from the more modern browsers.

The problem is that these `filter` styles are known to have numerous shortcomings and quirks, which mean that they do not always work very well, especially when used in conjunction with other browser features.

I've never tried using it with an image map, but I would be very surprised if these features worked properly together.

It's always possible that someone else may surprise me and find a solution, but my feeling is that you're just going to have to accept that this can't be done in IE8.

Your best bet may be to take a completely different approach. Rewrite your entire code to draw and animate the image using something like the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) library.

This library uses the browser's graphics system (VML in IE8, SVG in newer browsers), and will be able to display your image, rotate it, and provide clickable regions in a more cross-browser compatible way. (it would also have the advantage not having to use image maps, which are a somewhat out-dated technology)

This would give you a solution, but it does mean rewriting from scratch. I appreciate that may not be something you want to hear.

Comment: i found a way and will post the anwser. cant answer myself yet have to wait 8hours.
the solution is to use a transparent image with the imagemap and lay this over the original image. then only rotate the original image, so the imagemap never rotates.

Comment: @user2481955 - yep, that would work in your case, since your image map seems to be symetrical. It wouldn't work in most other similar cases. And I still recommend the SVG/VML solution as a better solution technically than using image maps.